# POST request over HTTPS causes error 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: jquery, https, jboss, download, http-post

I am using [jQuery fileDownload](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads) (created by [John Culviner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455556/john-culviner)) to load DOCX files that are dynamically generated by a JBoss server using RESTEasy. The application and file are on the same domain.

This works fine with documents that are fetched by HTTP GET.

However, in one case I have to use a HTTP **POST request**, so I can attach additional payload to the request. This also works in my local development environment, where I use HTTP. In production, however, the server is secured **by HTTPS**. There the file download does not work. In the browser console **I get an error 403 (Forbidden)** for the document's URL.

What is the problem here and how can I fix it? It seems like the browser cannot access the resource, but I'm not sure whether this is a client or a server problem. Do I have to set additional HTTP headers on either side? Or is this a JBoss configuration issue?

Since I cannot reproduce the problem locally, it is hard to debug.

---

Client code:

```
var downloadUrl = '/MyApp/foobar/download';

var downloadConfiguration = {
    httpMethod: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify($scope.payload),
    successCallback: onSuccess,
    failCallback: onError
};

$.fileDownload(downloadUrl, downloadConfiguration);
```

Server code:

```
@POST
@Path("/download")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces("text/word")
public Response generateDocument(final InputStream request) throws Exception {
  // ...

  Response.ResponseBuilder builder = null;
  File file = createMyDocument();

  builder = Response.ok((Object)file);
  builder.header("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s.%s\"", FILENAME, EXTENSION));
  builder.header("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");

  return builder.build();
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

I have also tried setting additional HTTP headers, but it did not help:

```
builder.header("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
builder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

I have added a [Security Constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html#bncbk) to `web.xml` for the download URL, but it did not help:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Foobar-Download</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/foobar/download</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>SOMEROLE</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

---

**EDIT 3:** The jQuery fileDownload plug-in uses an `iframe` with a hidden form for downloading. Maybe this interferes with the HTTPS connection? Some sort of CORS issue?

Comment: how big is the file ? Maybe you reached max response size ? Just blind guess. On other hand @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) but you're sending JSON ?

Comment: It is a small DOCX document, not bigger than those I retrieve with HTTP GET. The jQuery extension uses a `<form>` element to send the request, but it contains JSON. On HTTP this all works fine.

Comment: you can try fiddler https://www.telerik.com/fiddler to debug https session. It might shade some light on the problem

Comment: We've used Rackspace and had CORS issues when connecting over HTTPS to download files. For us, we needed to add the domains we were coming from to the configuration on the CDN - have you seen any Access-Control-Allow-Origin settings on your server?

Comment: Can you try to add a specific route for the CORS: @OPTIONS
@Path("/{path:.*}")
public Response handleCORSRequest() final String requestHeaders) {
    final ResponseBuilder retValue = Response.ok();
    retValue.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 'POST, GET');
    retValue.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return retValue.build();
}
} do you have something like that? My assumption is that locally no CORS req is made and maybe on server, the CORS req allow only GET(look at Access-Control-Allow-Methods if is set somewhere).

Comment: If the errors happens because of CORS it will be shown in the console as such. Can you post the console logs and as well as the network tab logs?

Comment: ``POST 403 (Forbidden)`` is the only output in console.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your firewall configurations on server? I apologize if I am saying something obvious but, the first time you make a requisition to a server and it's not from the same directory and it is not set to allow any origin ( the allow *) you will get errors. After the first usage with the allow origin * you can make a local request for example from you machine, and then the server should accept it. Tell me if you get something.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the server has a servlet security filter active which does not allow posting requests to the rest endpoint. Have you tried increasing the debug level of JBOSS and check the logs for a culprit?

I'm almost 100% sure it has nothing to do with http/https (or somebody implemented very strange logic).

Answer (score 1):

Your request is a Json encoded and your server is waiting for a form encoded.

Try to change your request data object to [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess this has to do with JBOSS SSL configuration. I suggest you start there and work your way back.